# Regex 1 or 2 liner - Is it possible?

Tags: c#, regex

Can a one/two liner regex be created to do the following?

I want to find this json data:

```
string ourdata = @"{
    'Field1':'Some ""awesome"" One',
    'Field2':'second field',
    'Field3':'/path/to/image.jpg',
    'Field4':'f4data',
    'Field5':'f5data',
    'Field6':'f6data',
    'Field7':'f7data',
    'Field8':'f8data',
    'Field9':'f9data',
    'Field10':'f10data',
    'Field11':'f11data',
    'Field12':'f12data',
    'AnotherField':'some field'
}";
```

within this, and replace the ||FieldX|| with the corresponding json data:

```
string fakeDoc = @"
    <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>
    <svg xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"" background=""#ffffff"" xmlns:svg=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" version=""1.2"" width=""1758"" height=""1292"" viewBox=""0 0 1758 1292"" id=""SVGCanvas"">
    <flowRoot id=""return_address_root"" font-size=""36px"" font-family=""Arial"" fill=""#000000"">
        <flowRegion id=""return_address_region"">
            <rect width=""600"" height=""150"" x=""64"" y=""65"" fill=""none"" id=""return_address_shape""/>
        </flowRegion>
        <flowDiv id=""return_address""><flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field1||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field2||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field3||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field5||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field1||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field2||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field4||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field5||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field6||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field7||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field8||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||Field9||]]></flowPara>
            <flowPara xml:space=""preserve""><![CDATA[||AnotherField||]]></flowPara>
        </flowDiv>
    </flowRoot>
    </svg>";
```

Is it possible?

**---UPDATE---**

This is what I have right now:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(ourdata);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fakeDoc);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in values)
    sb.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: What's a line? 79 characters? 256?

Comment: heh... that's why I said 1/2 liner.  But, of course, it doesn't have to be that. I'm just looking for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you've obviously parsed your JSON into a dictionary. Fine by me. Following regular expression will get your variable names as named capture group from our XML string:

```
@"\|\|(?<variableName>[^|]+)\|\|"
```

This expression can be used in a loop that replaces all corresponding variables.